# comparing two dates with different format in C

Tags: c

I want to compare two dates "2010-08-12" and "2010-8-12" but using strcmp it is failing so please suggest any inbuilt C function or any C function to compare these dates.

Regards

Comment: strings (from users and/or files) go in, parsing/error checking occurs, then... dates should be in "seconds since epoc" integers before you need to compare them or do anything else with them, then... data converted back to strings for any output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a simple and straightforward function to convert a date to a number that is good enough for ordering purposes by using [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/):

```
int seq_day(char *date) {
    int y = strtol(date, &date, 10);
    int m = strtol(++date, &date, 10);
    int d = strtol(++date, &date, 10);
    return (y*12+m)*31+d;
}
```

Call the above function on both dates, and compare the `int` results; the returned value will be smaller for the earlier date.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try [strptime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) and see if it fits.